# How to create angular cards with details drawer?

Tags: angular

We are trying to implement a tiles/cards layout in Angular 7 with a material design, which has similar functionality as a lot of modern image search engines have.

Here is an [example](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unicorn&atb=v115-1&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hdwallpaper.nu%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F12%2Funicorn-11.png)

Creating the tiles is not that difficult, but creating the drawer (is that the correct term) with details about the tile below it that appears on click, is harder.

Certainly when you take responsiveness into account. When you narrow the screen of the example search query, the beautiful images that are to the right of the selected images will move to a location left of the first row below the details drawer when the window is to narrow for it to fit on the screen.

As most search engines implement such a features, we were wondering whether there is a library that can provide us with these features.

I have tried searching for the better part of the day but so far I have not come up with a proper candidate, either because I do not know the proper search terms, or it does not exist.

What I found that came as close as it got:

- https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/components/cards/
- https://masonry.desandro.com
- https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples

And if there are no libraries that you know of, what would be a good startingpoint?

I know this sounds a little like "please help me by coding it for me", but we already have invested too many hours on this with a few people. We just cannot find a good starting point for this.

Comment: I think this might help a little [link](https://codepen.io/nailaahmad/pen/LGRxWJ)

Comment: wow, yes, this most certainly looks the part! it is for angular.js, but if you add it as an answer I will mark it as such

Comment: Now with the design in place, it's easier to manage the css classes with AngularJS.

Comment: we use Angular 7, AngularJs is very out dated, but none the less, the example can help us get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $cell = $('.card');

//open and close card when clicked on card
$cell.find('.js-expander').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  if ($thisCell.hasClass('is-collapsed')) {
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-inactive');
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded');
    
    if ($cell.not($thisCell).hasClass('is-inactive')) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      $cell.not($thisCell).addClass('is-inactive');
    }

  } else {
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');
  }
});

//close card when click on cross
$cell.find('.js-collapser').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
  $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #eceef1;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  color: #333a45;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 5em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}
.header {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.header__title {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.header__subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #949fb0;
  font-family: 'Yesteryear', cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.cards {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.card {
  margin: 15px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 30px);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.card:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
.card__inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #949fb0;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.card__inner:after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card__inner .fa {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
.card__expander {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #333a45;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #eceef1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.card__expander .fa {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card__expander .fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.card.is-collapsed .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
}
.card.is-collapsed .card__expander {
  max-height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333a45;
}
.card.is-expanded .card__inner .fa:before {
  content: "\f115";
}
.card.is-expanded .card__expander {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.card.is-expanded:hover .card__inner {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.card.is-inactive .card__inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.card.is-inactive:hover .card__inner {
  background-color: #949fb0;
  transform: scale(1);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+3) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-200% - 60px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(300% + 60px);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(2n+2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(200% + 30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="header__title">Expanding Card Grid</h1>
    <h2 class="header__subtitle">with Flexbox</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="cards">

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i>
        Expander
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think StackOverflow wants you not to just link to an internet source, but also add the code to your post for when the link dies

Comment: Now it will never die @DaniëlTulp